# How to specify 1 to many and many to 1 relations in json-ld document?

Tags: rest, httpresponse, json-ld

How can I specify one to many and many to one relations in json-ld.
For example :

```
{
  "@context" : {
    "@vocab" : "http://www.schema.org/",
    "@id" : "http://www.example.com/users/Joe",
    "name" : "name",
    "dob" : "birthDate",
    "age" : {
       "@id" : "http://www.example.com/users/Joe#age",
       "@type" : "Number"
        }
    "knows" : ["http://www.example.com/users/Jill", "http://www.example.com/users/James"]
    },
   "name" : "Joe",
   "age" : "24",
   "dob" : "12-Jun-2013"
}
```

this doesn't parse in json-ld playground.
What is the valid and best way to specify relations like this either in json-ld or using Hydra?

Comment: (1) In the `@context`, you have `"date" : "birthDate"`, but you are using `dob` later on: Is this a typo? (2) Schema.org does not define an `age` property, so is this a typo or do you want to use a different vocabulary for this? (3) Should the URI `http://www.example.com/users/Joe` be the identifier of this node? (i.e., you give the name/age/birthday of `http://www.example.com/users/Joe`?)

Comment: (1) and (2) were typo which I've edited,
(3) Yes I want to give the name/age/birthday of http://www.example.com/users/Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be carful what you put into the context and what you put into the body of the document. Simply speaking the context defines the mappings to URLs while the body contains the actual data. Your example should thus look something like this:

```
{
  "@context" : {
    "@vocab" : "http://www.schema.org/",
    "dob" : "birthDate",
    "age" : {
      "@id" : "http://www.example.com/users/Joe#age",
      "@type" : "Number"
    },
    "knows": { "@type": "@id" }
  },
  "@id" : "http://www.example.com/users/Joe",
  "name" : "Joe",
  "age" : "24",
  "dob" : "12-Jun-2013",
  "knows" : [
    "http://www.example.com/users/Jill",
    "http://www.example.com/users/James"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this is for the Objects of same kind,
Consider if the objects are of different kind, say for example I want to add another relation **likes** which would include objects of 
`http://www.example.com/reading/novels,
http://www.example.com/reading/blogs,
http://www.example.com/sports/soccer`

Then how can I specify this kind of relation in the context?

Comment: Can I specify like this?
`{
"@context" : {
...
"blogs" : {
"@id" : "http://www.example.com/reading/blogs",
"@type" : "Blog"
},
"novels" : {
"@id" : "http://www.example.com/reading/novels",
"@type" : "Book"
},
"sports" : {
"@id" : "http://www.example.com/sports",
"@type" : "sport"
},
"likes" : {
"@id" : "http://www.example.com/users/Joe#Likes",
"@set" : [ "novels", "blogs", "sports"],
"@type" : "LikeAction"
}
},
"@id" : "http://www.example.com/users/Joe",
...,
"likes" : [
"http://www.example.com/reading/novels",
"http://www.example.com/reading/blogs",
"http://www.example.com/sports/soccer"
]
}`

Comment: I want to use a python dictionary instead of a list, so like `"knows" : {
    "Jill":{"@id": "http://www.example.com/users/Jill"},
    "James":{"@id":"http://www.example.com/users/James"
  }` to address directly the objects without having to iterate and search in them. Is there a way?